# How to get individual items out of an array - jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, image

I am pulling an array of images out of a JSON file, and I have html img where I am placing the src of the image in:

html:

```
<img class="photos" src="" alt="" />
```

JS:

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
     var $div = $(".venue:first").clone();
     data.[i].photos;
     $div.find(".photos").attr("src", data[i].photos);
}
```

[EDIT]

```
JSON: 
comedyData([
    {
        "name": "Broadway Comedy Club",
        "checkinsCount": 2695,
        "tipCount": 36,
        "phone": "2127572323",
        "canonicalUrl": "https://foursquare.com/v/broadway-comedy-club/4afcb158f964a520212522e3",
        "mayor": "David M.",
        "mayor_photo": "https://img-s.foursquare.com/userpix_thumbs/1DFPPSPYD3N2DHBA.jpg",
        "address": "318 West 53rd St, New York, NY 10019",
        "photos": [
            "https://img-s.foursquare.com/derived_pix/0UZLALW0AOLS5NECIKPJQJ15BEUOTFSASYTF3JPWOPO4S130_100x100.jpg",
            "https://img-s.foursquare.com/derived_pix/MMP15NDCGLEC2GKJZEHIVLWLUXJ2IVZHM0DR1Z2K22MQF0PR_100x100.jpg",
            "https://img-s.foursquare.com/derived_pix/RNW1WQQS3BKGMAJT3VV5RJ5XDBQ4FJ1WAGBREWLAWWSM41VB_100x100.jpg",
            "https://img-s.foursquare.com/derived_pix/RI1LT5EUNKFN3303TRI23F0WKCCICOIHNGXTTXDLDEIH454V_100x100.jpg",
            "https://img-s.foursquare.com/derived_pix/0VACIGDCLHHS4FKZO13EDO5SCOCAKGLRE04DSR3B0WT3E0X0_100x100.jpg",
            "https://img-s.foursquare.com/derived_pix/Q2GHCRHSUEUL3AQELVE3KSMP3SMUBDXBWIGXAVSMEKPDVPAQ_100x100.jpg"
        ]
    }
```

My problem is it puts the array of images in the image attribute, but I just want one at a time.  I'm not sure how to get the individual images out of the array and place them in the html image src?

Comment: Can you show us what your JSON file looks like?

Comment: can I please see the json you are pulling from and also the html surrounding

Comment: Please, Provide the structure of JSON i.e. data. So, We could guide you.

Answer (score 1):

You can supply a `function(i, attr)` into your `.attr()`

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
     var $div = $(".venue:first").clone();
     data.[i].photos;
     $div.find(".photos").attr("src", function(index, src){
        return data[i].photos[index];
     });
}
```